# Jumping into c++ (practice on prime factor tree)

Tags: c++, function, primes

**I got the following exercise:**

Design a program that finds all numbers from 1 to 1000 whose prime factors, when added together, sum up to a prime number (for example, 12 has prime factors of 2, 2, and 3, which sum to 7, which is prime). Implement the code for that algorithm.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

//function prototype
int PrimeFactor(int number);
bool isPrime(int PrimeOrNot);

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        PrimeFactor(i);
}

int PrimeFactor(int number) {
    int i;
    int firstsplit = 0;
    int secondsplit = 0;
    int nextSplit = 0;
    int afternextsplit = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 2; i < number; i++) //loop that find the number that split it to two number , the purpose is for buiding the factor tree. 
    {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            firstsplit = number / i;
            secondsplit = number / firstsplit;

            if (isPrime(firstsplit)) 
                sum = sum + firstsplit;

            if (isPrime(secondsplit)) 
                sum = sum + secondsplit;

            break;
        }
    }

    if (isPrime(firstsplit) == false) //check if the splitted number is not already a factor from previous loop.
    {
        while (isPrime(firstsplit) == false) {
            for (i = 2; i < firstsplit; i++) //loop that continue to split the splitted number for the purpose of prime factors.
            {
                if (firstsplit % i == 0) {
                    nextSplit = firstsplit / i;
                    afternextsplit = firstsplit / nextSplit;

                    if (isPrime(nextSplit)) 
                        sum = sum + nextSplit;

                    if (isPrime(afternextsplit)) 
                        sum = sum + afternextsplit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool isPrime(int PrimeOrNot) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < PrimeOrNot; i++) {
        if (PrimeOrNot % i == 0) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Question:**

I think my program seems to be not so efficient, because there are a lot of variables and I suppose it can be done with less. Can anybody help me a bit with finding another way of doing it by a prime factor tree?

**Prime tree example:**

```
    16
   / \
  4    4
 /\   /\
2  2 2  2
```

Comment: So the program itself is working fine, you basically just want a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , no the code is not working (program isn't finished) , what i am asking is if maybe someone can tell me if that is the way ( i do know there is a more then one way to accoplish a program and that amazing but in my way there is a lot of variable for that kind of program and be much more , so if anybody can look at code and tell me that isn't the way , try to think about it (abc) or is a good way go further.

Comment: If you are just learning, concentrate on getting the job done! It seems to me you're doing fine so far. I don't know if the code runs, but you have functions that perform *functions*, and make good use of local variables instead of throwing all into the global pool. Only thing: a function that promises to return an `int` should do so - or make it `void`. Come back here if you run into actual problems, and if it runs but you think it can be better, submit on Code Review.

Comment: You've got two questions: 1) is there a better way to to it. 2) can someone review my code. The first question is on-topic for this website. The second is better suited for codereview website. If learning C++ is your goal, you may want to follow your own idea until completion. And only when you've got a working program look at other's solution.

Comment: `my program seems to be not so efficient, because there are a lot of variables ` That is a false assumption, at least at this level of programming. Don't worry at all about the number of variables, especially since you got into the good habit of giving them meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

This is one efficient way of solving your task. I am using sieve for which you can refer https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sieve-in-c++/answer/Ankit-Vallecha

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

#define N 1000
int flag[N+1];  // flag[i] =0 means i is prime, flag[i] =1 means i is not prime
int primes[N+1]; // primes[i] contains the (i+1)th prime, like prime[0]=2, prime[1]=3, prime[2]=5...
int len=0; // len determines the length of primes array filled

void sieve(){ // this function calculates all the primes less than N in primes array and number of primes is in len.

    for( int i=2; i<=sqrt(N); i++ ){
        if( flag[i] == 0 )
            for( int j=2*i; j<=N; j+=i )
                flag[j] = 1;
    }
    // now after this first loop flag[i] is ready to determine prime

    for( int i=2; i<=N; i++ )
        if( flag[i] == 0 )
            primes[len++] = i;

    // now primes contain the primes
}

bool isFactorSumPrime( int x ){ // this functions check whether sum of prime factors is prime or not
    int sum = 0; // sum of factors
    for( int i=0; i<len; i++ ){
        if( x==1 ) break; // x has no prime factors
        while( x%primes[i] == 0 ){  // if primes[i] is factor of x
            sum += primes[i];
            x /= primes[i];
        }
    }
    return !flag[sum];
}

int main(){
    sieve();
    for( int i=2; i<=N; i++ )
        if( isFactorSumPrime(i) == true )
            cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```